# Should I use node.js for my singe-page-app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, seo, client-side

I've built a Backbone.js app that does all the heavy-lifting, such as templating, translations and data loading, client side. (The application is basically a framework for educational material - videos and interactive visualizations - and does so far not include any significant *real-time features*.)

> Still, I'm pondering if I'd better use node.js for some features  ...?

**SEO**
Is JSDOM or other node.js library mature enough to serve rendered templates to the client?

**Desktop**
In the near future, is it conceivable to distribute an .exe / .app with node.js running locally? And which framework should I be looking at?

**Translations / i18n**
Would it be a good idea to use node.js for looking up translations and to build a translation dashboard for translators?

**Database**
Should I also use node.js for querying my database (probably *SQLite* as I'd like to mirror it locally) for User and Other data or stick with PHP/Ruby backend?

*All in all, what am I missing if I stick to my original client-side approach; could my JavaScript framework for navigating and interacting with educational material benefit from including node.js from  an early point?*

Comment: What do you mean by "Is JSDOM or other node.js library mature enough to serve pre-rendered markup to the client?"? Pre-rendered markup?

Comment: @999: Yes, that might be the wrong term. I mean, my current approach is to let for example Backbone "fill in" an html template using a templating library. I figure it would make more sense to do this server-side and then deliver it to the client so that spiders see the same content ..? Please suggest a better term and I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 3):

**SEO:** I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for, but node.js has many usable templating engines. you can find these through the wiki

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-templating

or npm (node package manager):

http://search.npmjs.org/

Also, there are frameworks such as Express.js that include the ability to use templating to serve pages, but the templating engine is switchable to almost any package.

http://expressjs.com/

**Desktop:** you can check out the Titanium app with a local running node instance here.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/06/titanium-desktop-node-js-prototype.html

**Translations and Databases:** I don't know a whole lot about translations, but I assume you'll need a database to store your translations and node.js has many capable libraries for talking to databases. This doesn't sound like a node.js problem so much as a choice of database problem. You have your choice of many SQL and NoSQL solutions.

It will be up to you to decide if you want to use node.js as only you know the true scope of your project.